# Как прикрутить яндекс.кассу в приложении android

Tags: android, яндекс-касса

Возникла необходимость прикрутить яндекс кассу в приложении. Api под android позволяет сделать оплату с банковской карты. Есть ли идеи как привязать другие  способы оплаты из кассы?
Важно использование именно этой платежки.